# How to restrict the app to iphone only and preserve this setting

Tags: nativescript

Normally I can go to Xcode -> General -> Deployment info -> Devices and set iPhone there. The Xcode project is not something always preserved with Nativescript application and can be added / removed often (i.e. on plugin updates). Is there a way to still keep this restriction setting somewhere? I thought about *.plist file, but when I change this setting in Xcode I don't see any changes to *.plist being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that you could try is to set up the UIDeviceFamily in your project Info.plist. For this key, you could set 1 for iPhones or 2 for iPads. For example:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for your answer. When I add this, rebuild the project and open it in Xcode I see Universal in Deployment info -> Devices. Should not that be changed to iPhone?

Comment: The official documentation advises against setting this value in the Info.plist manually: "Important: Do not insert this key manually into your Info.plist files. Xcode inserts it automatically based on the value in the Targeted Device Family build setting. You should use that build setting to change the value of the key.". More information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11